# If the flu vaccine is the exact same as last year, would it still offer protection this year?

Tags: immunology

I understand why the flu shot changes and that's why we get an annual vaccine; however, if the vaccine is the same as last year, wouldn't people theoretically still have the same antibodies this year? Do antibodies disappear after a year?

Answer (score 2):

If one flu strain wouldn't change between the years (meaning there wouldn't be any new mutations in it) and the same strain would circulate again in the following year, the "old" vaccination would protect people. This is the same as with other viruses which do not change, once you reached a protection (usually one basic immunization and one booster), this protects for a long time (see measles vaccination as an example here).

There are surprisingly little articles available on how long the immune response after a vaccination lasts. There is a difference between the livettenuated influenza vaccine (LAIV) and the inactivated influenza virus (IIV), with the former giving a less good protection (see reference 1).
Data for the LAIV suggests that there is protection for at least one year after the vaccination (see reference 2).

However, there is evidence that the immunity against the flu after an infection against this specific strain might last life-long, as a paper demonstrated on survivors of the 1918 flu epidemic (see reference 3).

Having the flu against being vaccinated against it is a complete different thing (higher exposure, probably more antigens), but the question is if the immune response against vaccinations may also for a longer time.
The problem with the flu vaccination are:

- The strain circulating in a year is changing.
- The stains are mutating, making them different from the virus used for vaccine production. Depending on how different these mutations make the circulating strain, it can render the vaccine more or less useless. This is something what happened this flu season.
- The flu vaccine is prepared from different flu strains to cover a broader range. In a tri-valent vaccine these are typically 2 Influenza A and one Influenza B virus strains, in tetra-valent vaccines 2 A and 2 B strains. The composition is based on a prediction (from epidimiologic data) which strains are likely to circulate in the next season and is done early in the year for the following season (production takes time, etc.).

Because of these problems, researchers are working on a universal flu vaccine; which is based on virus parts which do not change and should protect against all virus strains. Then only the basic vaccination would be necessary as with other vaccinations.

With all these limitations, it is still advisable to get a flu vaccination, as it is a pretty severe infection.

When not challenged (i.e. upon infections) antibodies are cleared from the blood within a few weeks, but there are low amounts produced (which are enough for detection). The immunologic memory is maintained by memory B cells which can ramp up production of the highly specific antibodies in a very short time - this is the reason for the protection by immunizations.

References:

1. [Modest Waning of Influenza Vaccine Efficacy and Antibody Titers
   During the 2007-2008 Influenza Season.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27095420)
2. [Longevity of B-cell and T-cell responses after live attenuated
   influenza vaccination in children.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25425696)
3. [Neutralizing antibodies derived from the B cells of 1918 influenza
   pandemic survivors](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature07231)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is concerning as there have been many children dying from the B strain, that experts are claiming is the one covered in the vaccine. The vaccine is exactly the same as last year, so wondering if those who received the vaccine last year would have some protection, obviously taking into account changes and mutations

Comment: The majority of deaths usually occurs in the non vaccinated.

Comment: Chris, can you support your claim of prolonged immunity against influenza vaccine (i.e. antibody persistence)? Some viruses do have astounding antibody persistence. Others have little.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Yes, there are some papers, I will dig them out. There was especially one paper on survivors of the 1918 flu. It has to wait, until I have paper access again at work.

Comment: So in saying this. Antibodies that have developed after receiving the flu vaccine does not wear off after a year, correct? So someone that received the shot in Canada last year but not this year, would have the same level of antibodies, as someone who received it this year. As the vaccine has the exact same strains included in the shot as last year. Is this correct